# Java says a nonempty file is empty?

Tags: java, file-io

I have a [particular file](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/123623/test.f) that Java says is empty...

**Source Code**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MinimumWorkingExample
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        String filename = "/home/tyson/Data/English-French_test/test/test.f";
        Scanner fileIn = new Scanner(new File(filename));
        System.out.println("***START***");
        while(fileIn.hasNextLine())
        {
            System.out.println(fileIn.nextLine());
        }
        System.out.println("***FINISH***");
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
***START***
***FINISH***
```

...but the file is not empty:

**Console**

```
tyson@tyson-desktop:~$ head /home/tyson/Data/English-French_test/test/test.f
<s snum=0001> 2 .  </s>
<s snum=0002> 2 .  </s>
<s snum=0003> oh , oh !  </s>
<s snum=0004> oh , oh !  </s>
<s snum=0005> oh , oh !  </s>
<s snum=0006> souvenons - nous , monsieur le Orateur , que ce sont ces secteurs de notre soci�t� qui servent de �pine dorsale � notre �conomie .  </s>
<s snum=0007> bravo !  </s>
<s snum=0008> bravo !  </s>
<s snum=0009> monsieur le Orateur , ma question se adresse � le ministre charg� de les transports .  </s>
<s snum=0010> tous deux poss�dent de nombreuses ann�es de exp�rience dans la fabrication et la distribution de les produits forestiers .  </s>
tyson@tyson-desktop:~$
```

**Question**

Why is this happening???

Comment: I tried your program with the attached file and I am able to read the contents of the file correctly.

Comment: @Jugal In a comment to an answer below, Joop suggested that since the file is in French, I should use `Scanner fileIn = new Scanner(new File(filename), "Cp1252");` to read the file properly. This fix works for me. Out of curiosity, know of any reason why your system can correctly read French by default (but mine can't)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also do Scanner fileIn = new Scanner(new File(filename), "Cp1252"); as this is the encoding for French, and your system seems to be UTF-8.
The Scanner might have encoding problems if it thinks to read UTF-8 multibytes.

Answer (score 0):

You may be missing the Scanner's default delimiter so it sees your whole file as one line without end, thus hasNextLine() is false.  Make sure that the character you get from

```
Scanner.delimiter()
```

Is present in your file.  If they don't match, you can use

```
Scanner.useDelimiter("\\s or your regex/string here")
```

to set it to the correct one.

Comment: Also do Scanner fileIn = new Scanner(new File(filename), "Cp1252"); as this is the encoding for French, and your system seems to be UTF-8

Comment: Even if the whole file has only one line, `hasNextLine()` should return `true` for that first line, right?  Then, of course, it would return `false` subsequently.

Comment: @Joop your suggestion to use `Scanner fileIn = new Scanner(new File(filename), "Cp1252");` worked! Make an official answer saying as much I will accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

According to Java Docs, the Line Separators are any of the ones below. Does your file contain any?

```
private static final String LINE_SEPARATOR_PATTERN = "\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085]"
```