# Scanner not reading file

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am trying to make a method that reads words from a file and saves them in a string named common.

After this, it should compare the words in common to the words in a list of strings (not an `ArrayList`) and remove any of the nodes in the list that appear in the file (or the string common).

When I compile this program, it works fine. It also runs. However, for some reason, it just **skips over the while loop**.

```
private void removeCommonEnglishWords() {   
    Scanner infile = null;
    try {
        infile = new Scanner( new FileInputStream( "filename" ) );
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Nope");
    }

    String common = "";
    while (infile.hasNext()) {
        common = common + infile.next() + " ";
    }

    for (int k = 0; k < terms.size(); k++) {
        if (common.contains(terms.get(k))) {
          terms.remove(k);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't forget to **close** the resource after using (or use *try-with-resources*).

Comment: What does your file contain? Give a complete example ([mcve]). Why do you think it *skips* the while-part? If you place a `System.out.println("hi");` inside, does it show, how often?

Comment: Learn to use the debugger. Set a breakpoint at the first line in the code and step through it in the debugger to see what's happening. And if you're going to use `catch`, then actually do something with the exception instead of just ignoring it, and you'll get some information that's useful when things go wrong. Your code is written like you're the legendary ostrich sticking his head in the sand - *If I pretend an exception doesn't exist, then it doesn't happen*.

Comment: @KenWhite Printing "Nope" is okay for a small program I'd say. At least he knows that a problem occurred. Also the program will throw `NPE` shortly after, it won't continue. Nonetheless a useful tip.

Comment: @Zabuza: Of course, unless the exception gives actual information that could be used to solve the problem (like a message telling you why the exception was raised, which printing *Nope* throws away). If you don't know exactly why you're doing so, don't ignore the exception or the information it contains. This poster clearly isn't experienced or knowledgeable enough yet to be ignoring them, whether it's in a small program or not, or this question wouldn't be here and we wouldn't be having this discussion. :-)

Comment: ok to respond to these: You do not have to close the scanner, it automatically does so in Java 8 but I should probably do that.  The file is an unknown number of lines, and it is listed as one word for lines.  It skips the whole entire while loop.  Ken, I know how to use the debugger.  I tried that.  It skips over the while loop and I don't know why.  The "nope" is there because its the only section that I have to use a try catch, and its not even throwing the exception anyways.

Answer (score 0):

If it's skipping over the while loop, then that means your only possible problem is "infile" is not getting defined, and it is either null from your initialization, or it is simply empty.

Actually, from looking at this code snibbit, that would make sense.  Above in your code this is the only thing that is running in your try block:

```
try {
      infile = new Scanner( new FileInputStream( "filename" ) );
}

// By the way you should use this instead
try( /*initialized resources here */ ) {
     //Do work here
}
```

All your work needs to be inside this try block.  This is because if something were to happen with the input stream, or your code fires an exception, it needs to be properly handled.  The try (with resources) block I mentioned above automatically tries closing your declared resources directly after the try block, before the code execution continues.  This is mainly a security reason, so other users can't get a hold of your resource and manipulate it.

For instance your code block might look something like the bellow (I'm putting dummy example code here):

```
try ( FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("server/file.txt")) {
    // Do work.
    byte[] byteArray = new byte[9]();
    fos.write(byteArray);

// Try with resources block will automatically try closing the resources, 
//but if there are any errors, they are suppressed.  You can still print the 
//supressed errors, but you will have to write extra code for this.
} catch(Exception e) {
    // Always print out logs, so you know what went wrong!
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println("Whoops! There was an error, please fix.");
}
```

[Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) is the docs on try with resources, if you want to read more :)

Also, you didn't specify anything about the file name, but are you sure you have the right path to your file?

Comment: ok thanks, I'll try that, and I got the file path through the file properties, so I'm fairly certain it's correct.

Comment: ok, it didn't work.  I'm not sure whats going on, because it/s going through the whole thing without throwing the exception.  Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think that means that it is instantiating the scanner just fine, meaning it either has the wrong file (doubtful), or I have no idea what is going on.

Comment: The problem is similar to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8598702/java-says-a-nonempty-file-is-empty       However, my file is not in french

Comment: If you have the path correct, then the scanner has your file.  It looks like it is being instantiated correctly and seems to be trying to scan your file.  Could you post an updated code snibit of what your trying to do now?  Or perhaps you could put a run-able example on a site like code.sololearn.com

Also have you tried setting the delimeter like in this answer?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8598737/8875844